# no web dynos in heroku for an AngluarJS project

Tags: git, angularjs, heroku

I recently deployed a new version of my AngularJS project to Heroku.  I am developing the project in Yeoman with Firebase as the backend.

```
unknownc8e0eb148153:newTic christopherspears$ git push heroku master
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 524 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Node.js app detected

       PRO TIP: Avoid using semver ranges starting with '>' in engines.node
       See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support

-----> Requested node range:  >=0.8.0
-----> Resolved node version: 0.10.24
-----> Downloading and installing node
-----> Installing dependencies
       npm WARN package.json newtic@0.0.0 No description
       npm WARN package.json newtic@0.0.0 No repository field.
       npm WARN package.json newtic@0.0.0 No README data
-----> Caching node_modules directory for future builds
-----> Cleaning up node-gyp and npm artifacts
-----> Procfile not found and npm start script is undefined

       PRO TIP: Create a Procfile or specify a start script in package.json
       See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support

-----> Building runtime environment
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)

-----> Compressing... done, 5.3MB
-----> Launching... done, v13
       http://new-tic.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:new-tic.git
   74bdc98..11235fe  master -> master
```

Unfortunately, I now have issues running the app from heroku.  For some reason, I cannot get any web dynos.

```
unknownc8e0eb148153:newTic christopherspears$ heroku ps:scale web=1
Scaling dynos... failed
 !    Resource not found
```

Not sure what the issue is.  I do see a heroku directory with a Procfile in it.

```
unknownc8e0eb148153:heroku christopherspears$ ls
Procfile          distpackage.json  server.js
unknownc8e0eb148153:heroku christopherspears$ cat Procfile 
web: node server.js
```

Does the Procfile need to be moved out of the heroku directory?

UPDATE:

I have three files in the heroku directory: Procfile, distpackage.json, and server.js.  I copied all three files to the root directory, and then I did a git add and commit and pushed everything to Heroku.

I then scaled up the dynos:

```
unknownc8e0eb148153:newTic christopherspears$ heroku ps:scale web=1
Scaling dynos... done, now running web at 1:1X.
```

My app now has one web dyno running.  However, I am getting this error message when I run 'heroku open':

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

I checked the logs and found this:

```
2014-01-12T07:41:50.557774+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2014-01-12T07:41:51.418817+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:340
2014-01-12T07:41:51.419069+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2014-01-12T07:41:51.419069+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2014-01-12T07:41:51.422074+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
2014-01-12T07:41:51.422074+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
2014-01-12T07:41:51.418549+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-01-12T07:41:51.422074+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'statik'
2014-01-12T07:41:51.422074+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2014-01-12T07:41:51.422074+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2014-01-12T07:41:51.422074+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:3:14)
2014-01-12T07:41:51.422074+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2014-01-12T07:41:51.422074+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2014-01-12T07:41:51.422074+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2014-01-12T07:41:51.422074+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2014-01-12T07:41:51.422265+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
2014-01-12T07:41:52.663455+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2014-01-12T07:41:52.681103+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-01-12T07:42:04.524226+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=new-tic.herokuapp.com fwd="108.70.100.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

The module 'statik' is mentioned in my server.js folder:

```
unknownc8e0eb148153:newTic christopherspears$ cat server.js 
'use strict';

var statik = require('statik');
var server = statik.createServer('.');
server.listen();
```

What is the statik module?

UPDATE:

Apparently, statik refers to this module: https://github.com/hongymagic/statik

I installed statik locally in my node_modules directory and then updated my distpackage.json  and package.json files with statik as a dependency.  I then removed node_modules from .gitignore and tried to push to heroku, but the push failed:

```
3100 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
3101 info jpegtran-bin@0.2.0 Failed to exec postinstall script
3102 error jpegtran-bin@0.2.0 postinstall: `node pre-build.js`
3102 error Exit status 8
3103 error Failed at the jpegtran-bin@0.2.0 postinstall script.
3103 error This is most likely a problem with the jpegtran-bin package,
3103 error not with npm itself.
3103 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
3103 error     node pre-build.js
3103 error You can get their info via:
3103 error     npm owner ls jpegtran-bin
3103 error There is likely additional logging output above.
3104 error System Linux 3.8.11-ec2
3105 error command "/tmp/build_bc4a037e-1d3c-4956-a90a-5121da17cf51/vendor/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_bc4a037e-1d3c-4956-a90a-5121da17cf51/vendor/node/bin/npm" "rebuild"
3106 error cwd /tmp/build_bc4a037e-1d3c-4956-a90a-5121da17cf51
3107 error node -v v0.10.24
3108 error npm -v 1.3.21
3109 error code ELIFECYCLE
3110 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app

To git@heroku.com:new-tic.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Sigh.  This issue just never seems to have an end.